# Ring menu for Windows

Tags: windows, menu

I'm looking for a program that can display a set of icons around the mouse cursor when the user hit a keyboard shortcut. Click on an icon would launch the corresponding program. The set of icons should be configurable, and should not necessarily include the running programs.

On Mac OS X I can use [Ring Menu](http://ring-menu.com/) (~ 5 USD):

[image: Screenshot of Ring Menu - 'Ring Menu: All your favorite apps are right at hand.']

[image: Screenshot of Ring Menu]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Circle Dock](http://circledock.wikidot.com/):

- free
- open source
- opens on shortcut
- looks nice
- customizable programs
- easy to use
- can move around/open where your mouse is
- can have programs/folders/files and add parameters to their launch
- close by shortcut/clicking in middle

[image]

(^^I've added Chrome to the 'dock' ^^)

Comment: Just be aware that the version from the website linked above is 0.9.1 (or 0.9.2 alpha). There are also sources for higher versions (up to 1.5.6) available around the web, but anything above 0.9.2 alpha was released illegally as the original developer stopped development, someone else picked it up, but then refused to release the updated source code.